# JavaScript not working on HTML file (Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I've got an express server to which I'm rendering my **payj.html** file which contains a script tag for the **clyint.js** file. But when I do that I get this error from the browser's console:

> ***GET https://iovyb.sse.codesandbox.io/views/clyint.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404***

I also tried including all my JS in the HTML file itself but that didn't work either, for some reason.

**ecspres.js**

```
// stop node prawsesiz: pkill -f node
var engines = require("consolidate");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.engine("html", engines.mustache);
app.set("view engine", "html");
// app.use(express.static("src"));
// app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8080);

var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("Server Up"); //now??
});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("payj.html");
});

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id + " joind");
  socket.on("Name", (name) => {
    console.log(name + " cunectid");
  });
});

// //create a server object:
// http
//   .createServer(function (req, res) {
//     res.write("Hello Server!"); //write a response to the client
//     res.end(); //end the response
//   })
//   .listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

**payj.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      td {
        border: 3px solid gray;
        width: 179px;
      }
      tr {
        height: 179px;
      }
      table {
        margin-top: 9.9%;
      }
    </style>
    <title>TTT!</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/styl.css" /> -->
    <!-- <script
      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"
      type="text/javascript" 
    ></script> -->
    <script src="views/clyint.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
        <td align="center"><img src="#" style="display: none;" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button>PLAY AGAIN</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**clyint.js**

```
// var name = window.prompt("hoo aar yoo");
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var soc = io("https://iovyb.sse.codesandbox.io/");

soc.emit("Name", "Dhroov");

function reset() {
  console.log("gei");
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  a = 0;
  while (a < x.length) {
    x[a].setAttribute("src", "");
    a++;
  }
}

var aTurn = true;
// $(window).load(function () {
var buts = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var a = 0;
console.log(buts.length);

while (a < buts.length) {
  // buts[a].addEventListener("click", clic);
  buts[a].setAttribute("id", a.toString());
  buts[a].addEventListener("click", function clic() {
    a = this.id;
    if (aTurn) {
      var t = document.querySelectorAll("td")[a];
      console.log(t);
      var td = t.querySelector("img");
      td.setAttribute("style", "");
      td.setAttribute("which", "cros");
      td.setAttribute("width", "79px");
      td.setAttribute(
        "src",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/12/20/12/x-30465_640.png"
      );
      t.style.marginLeft = "10px";
    } else {
      var t = document.querySelectorAll("td")[a];
      var td = t.querySelector("img");
      td.setAttribute("width", "99px");
      td.setAttribute("src", "https://otranscribe.com/favicon.png");
      td.setAttribute("which", "not");
      td.setAttribute("style", "");
      t.style.marginLeft = "10px";
    }
    aTurn = !aTurn;
    var but = document.querySelector("button");
    but.addEventListener("click", reset.bind());
  });

  a++;
}
// checking for win:
// a=0
// var num=0
// function checStrayt(hoo, from, to, dir){
//   var t = document.querySelectorAll("td")
//   while(true){
//     if(t[a].which==hoo)
//       num++;
//     else
//       break
//     if(dir==1)
//       a+=3
//     else if(dir==2)
//       a++
//     else

// }
```

Also, if it helps, this is my folder structure:

[image: Tree]

What shall I do?

Comment: you have to serve the `static` files by `express.static` middleware provided by `express`    
take a look at this webpage https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the static directory where you will be saving your static files.
in express you can do it using :

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

this is a middleware that seta the static folder.
the path '/' will point to the static directory in your HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your static files such as `js` , `css` and `images` in a separate folder, with a name, say, `public`
and in your `express.js` file add the following line before any of your `routes`,

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
```

for this you need to install `path` module using `npm install path` command

and in your `html` file just mention the name of the static file in you `script` or `link`

```
<script src="clyint.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I followed your steps but I'm getting the exact error message from the browser (the HTML loads but not JS). Could it have something to do with the online IDE (CodeSandBox)?